# Grails, jQuery and Ajax

Tags: grails

I want a select box which lists instructors (from a session `variable:session.eligibleInstructor.FULLNAME`), to update a textfield with the selected instructors email address (the email is also available in the same session variable: `session.eligibleInstructor.EMAIL`), when the instructor is selected in the selectbox. I know my javascript is capturing the selected instructor (because I did an "alert"):

```
$('#inst2Select').change(function(event){
  $('#emailInst2').load('/edu.wit.nonac/nonAcadCourse/create/updateSelect',
    {
      selectedInst: $(event.target).val()
    },
    function() {alert($(event.target).val())
}
```

but my controller action (updateSelect) is not doing anything:

```
def updateSelect = {
        //nonacCourseConsole3.url.root = "/edu.wit.nonac" + "/";
        println("UpdateSelect reached")
        def ctx = startAsync()

        ctx.start{
        println("Params: "  + params.any())
        def selectedInstEmail = dbConnection.firstRow("select EMAIL from  zV_eligibleInstructors where FIRSTNAME=?", [params.selectedInst])
        println(selectedInstEmail)
        render selectedInstEmail

        }


    }
```

I have tried multiple ajax-type callbacks , even a remoteFunction in the "onchange"event. I realize I should haven't to go back to the database to get the selected Instructors email because it's already avilable in the session variable. I have looked at hundreds of webpages for the answer but none seems to quite touch on this exact issue. Even if I could just get the controller action to fire, that would be a huge step forward. Does anyone have suggestiona as to what is wrong?

Comment: Get rid of all of the ctx garbage

Answer (score 0):

You can have your view generate a Javascript object structure with the full name of the instructor and their email address.  In your controller, you can build an instructorMap that maps the instructor's full name to their email address.  Then in your view you can have something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var instructors = {
    <g:each in="${instructorMap}" var="mapEntry">
      "${mapEntry.key}": "${mapEntry.value}",
    </g:each>
  }
</script>
```

Then in your change event handler, you can pull the value from the instructors variable.

This will only work if you can guarantee that the full names are unique.  If not, you can setup something similar two variables instructorNames (mapping id to full name) and instructorEmails (mapping id to email).

Comment: Thanks Nancy! I'll try that and get back!

Comment: I must be missing something still. I put in the onchange event:

Comment: onchange="\$('#emailInst2').val(selectedInst)"

Comment: and used this for the script:

Comment: var selectedInst = {
   <g:each in='${session.eligibleInstructors}' var='mapEntry'>
    '${mapEntry.FULLNAME}': '${mapEntry.EMAIL}',
   </g:each>
   
        }

Comment: eligibleInstructors is the session variable that has the instructors and their email addresses.